# Using a method from a template in a header that has been overloaded in a source

Tags: c++

I'm well aware that this is a really newbish question and I apologize for that, but I've been searching a lot and I couldn't find a solution.

I've got the following files:

headertest.hpp

```
template<typename t>
class HeaderTest {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        //HeaderTest();
        t addition(t a, t b);
};
```

ImplementationTest.cpp

```
#include "headertest.hpp"

template<typename t>
t HeaderTest<t>::addition(t a, t b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;
}
```

Let's say I wanted to sum those two ints x and y, how would I use my method addition for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;

    HeaderTest<int> ht; // Instantiate a HeaderTest

    int z = ht.addition(x, y); // Use its member function.
}
```

Note that template definitions should not be in cpp files. This works here because `main` is in the same file, but you must put it in the header for normal use.

**Edit:** about header/cpp issues.

You have understood it perfectly. Declarations (the interface) go in a header file, definitions (the implementation, that is, the actual code) go in a cpp file.

But, templates are the exception to this rule. A template's definition must be *fully accessible at the point of its instantiation*. That's a moutful to say that when you use a template, you must have included *all* of its source code (as opposed to "normal" objects, whose declarations suffice). What's the easiest way to do that ? Putting it all in the header.

If that seems unclean to you, there's an alternative : put your template definitions in a third file, often called "template implementation file" and extended .tpp. Then, just `#include` your tpp file at the bottom of your header file.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to "tell" what the method does in my source file and the header would only work as an interface, I've been reading a lot of the C++ documentation but it's still not quite clear to me where should I put what.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines to your main() function:

```
  HeaderTest<int> test;
  cout << test.addition(x, y);
```

So, you first have to create a HeaderTest object for integers. Next, as you defined addition as a member function, you can apply it to this test object for the integers x and y.